# Selecting first element with a particular class?

Tags: jquery

I have a number of divs on my page all with the class answer.

Using jquery how can I select only the first element with the class answer?

Thanks

Comment: `.first(), :first()` read the [jQuery api docs here](http://api.jquery.com/first/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) Selector:

> Selects the first matched element.
>
> The :first pseudo-class is equivalent to :eq(0). It could also be
>   written as :lt(1). While this matches only a single element,
>   :first-child can match more than one: One for each parent.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

`$(".answer:first")`

ref: http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

OR

`$(".answer").first()`

this will give you first elemnt of class answer

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/first/

Answer (score -1):

Use Jquery [first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/), for example:

```
$('li').first().css('background-color', 'red');
```

Or :first `$("li:first")`